# Find all positive integer solutions of the equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

Find all positive integer solutions of the equation $1650_x = 1131_3$$_y$ where $x$ and $3y$ are the bases of the numbers on the two sides.

I have this example in my book but have never come across an equation like this and I can't seem to find anything about these online.

Am I correct to by starting with

$1650_x = 1*x^3 + 6*x^2 +5*x^1 + 0*x^0 = x^3+6x^2+5x$

$1131_3$$_y = (3y)^3 + (3y)^2 + 9y + 1$

If so, where do I go from here?  If not, than I am lost.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: What are the residues of $$1650_x = x^3+6x^2+5x = x(x+1)(x+5)$$ and $$1131_{3y} = (3y)^3+(3y)^2+3(3y)+1 = 3(9y^3+3y^2+3y)+1$$ modulo $3$?

Comment: Ok, that does help.  I am thinking that x=0,2,1 from x(x+1)(x+5) mod 3 and y=2 from 3(9y^3+3y^2+3y)+1 mod 3 since it goes to y^3+y^2+y+1 = (y+1)(y^2+1) mod 3?  Hopefully I am thinking correctly on that.

Comment: It's not clear you understood my hint. Note that in order for $1650_x = 1131_{3y}$, we must have $1650_x \equiv 1131_{3y}\pmod{3}$, i.e. both numbers leave the same remainder when divided by $3$. Now, for each integer $y$, what is the remainder when $1131_{3y} = 3(9y^3+3y^2+3y)+1$ is divided by $3$? This should be easy. Similarly, for each integer $x$, what is the remainder when $1650_x = x(x+1)(x+5)$ is divided by $3$? This is a bit trickier to answer for all $x$, but if you try a few values of $x$, you'll see a pattern.

Comment: Ok, I have been on this for awhile and I guess I don't understand how to do mod 3 with equations.  Does $3(9y^3+3y^2+3y)+1$ mod 3 ≡ 1?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: What I'm hinting at is that $1650_x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ for all positive integers $x$, while $1131_{3y} \equiv 1\pmod{3}$ for all positive integers $y$. In other words, $1650_x$ is always a multiple of $3$, and $1131_{3y}$ is always one more than a multiple of $3$. Hence, $1650_x \neq 1131_{3y}$ for all positive integers $x,y$. See if you can prove what I stated here.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped me a ton.  I believe I have it now.  I did come up with that, but thought I was doing it all wrong because I assumed there had to be a solution. Guess I shouldn't assume.  Thanks again for the help.